# Media Queries não alteram conteúdo

Tags: html, css, flask, media-queries

Estou montando um site e fui acrescentar algumas media queries para a responsividade. Porém não tem alteração alguma no site quando o viewport é alterado, já troquei as variáveis de max para min-whidth, mas não altera em nada, o site apenas "diminui" de tamanho e nada do que está nas media queries é efetuado.
Também estou utilizando o Flask, não encontrei nada que fosse relacionado que pudesse estar dando problema.

CSS:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(16, 16, 16, .5);
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

CSS (media-queries):

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #header {
        left: -300px;
    }
    i.mobile_menu {
        display: flex;
    }
    section#start h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    section#start span#subtitle {
        font-size: 0.75rem;
        padding-left: 0.5rem;
    }
    #main {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

VIEWPORT:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

HTML:

```
<aside id="header">
        <section class="profile">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/img iago.jpeg') }}">
            <h1>Iago Rhudá Ramos</h1>
            <div class="social_links mt-4 text-center">
                <a href="https://github.com/iago-rhuda" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <i class="bi bi-github"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/iago-rhuda-ramos/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <i class="bi bi-whatsapp"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <nav id="navbar" class="nav_menu">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i> Início</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-file-person-fill"></i> Sobre mim</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-book"></i> Formação</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-box"></i> Experiências</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-award-fill"></i> Portfólio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-chat-text-fill"></i> Contato</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score -4):

Opa, dei uma olhada no seu CSS e aparentemente estava faltando o "screen and" na media, desta forma funcionou a media query como você deseja, faz um teste com esse código aí debaixo! :)

Aconselho a dar uma estudada sobre media query no site da W3S:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.5);
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #header {
    right: 300px;
    background: red;
  }
  i.mobile_menu {
    display: flex;
  }
  section#start h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  section#start span#subtitle {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  #main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <aside id="header">
    <section class="profile">
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/img iago.jpeg') }}">
      <h1>Iago Rhudá Ramos</h1>
      <div class="social_links mt-4 text-center">
        <a href="https://github.com/iago-rhuda" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          <i class="bi bi-github"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/iago-rhuda-ramos/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          <i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          <i class="bi bi-whatsapp"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <nav id="navbar" class="nav_menu">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i> Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-file-person-fill"></i> Sobre mim</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-book"></i> Formação</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-box"></i> Experiências</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-award-fill"></i> Portfólio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-chat-text-fill"></i> Contato</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Com seu código o resultado foi o mesmo, consegui perceber que com ele o ícone do menu aparecia, o que não ocorria antes. Mas alterando o #header na @media para aside#header ele funcionou perfeitamente